# Is there a way to install Windows Update manually without the Internet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

The PCs where I'm working do not have internet access as they contain sensitive data and are only connected to their VPN sites, and I do not want to connect the PCs to the internet for security purposes. Is there a safe offline installer for Windows?

I'd like to upgrade to Windows 10, 22H2 from Windows 10, 1909

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways this can be done. One of them is to simply use the [Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). That should provide the option to update on that machine if you plugin said Media.

Comment: Media Creation Tool requires an Internet connection

Comment: Every option requires an internet connection eventually short of buying retail media. He won't be able to run it on the target machien but preparing a USB Key or installation DVD on a different computer that has internet works and it can be used to update said machines.

Answer (score 1):

[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Download the latest ISO from Microsoft's page for
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10),
then do the In-place Upgrade by executing the Setup executable from the ISO.

You may also download individual updates from the
[Microsoft Update Catalog for Windows 10](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows%2010)
and install each one individually by executing the downloaded file.

Comment: Feature updates like 22H2 cannot be found on the Windows Update Catalog website , in other words, they cannot be downloaded separately and must be installed through the appropriate Windows ISO

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, indeed. To clarify my answer : The Windows Update Catalog  is only for updates that will arrive after the feature update.